# Callback function for array_filter

Tags: php, callback

```
class MyClass {
    private function isExist($arr) {
        // need to do some formatting here first

        // need to call in_array here to check whether to filter out duplicates
        return false; // temporary return value
    }

    public function test() {
        $data = array(
            array('foo' => 'alpha', 'bar' => 'bravo'),
            array('foo' => 'charlie', 'bar' => 'delta'),
            array('foo' => 'alpha', 'bar' => 'bravo'),
        );

        $result = array_filter($data, array('MyClass', 'isExist'));
        print_r($result);
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();
```

How to access the array being filtered within the callback function? And is it possible to pass one or two arguments to the callback function?

And I have PHP 5.3.1, just in case you'll need to know the version I am using.

EDIT:
// separate formatting and then call array_unique

Comment: array_filter iterates over each entry in the array and calls the callback. You cannot pass another parameter.

Are you trying to find unique entries in $data? i.e. Do you want $result to contain the first and second entries of $data, but not the third (since it is the same as the first)?

Comment: "Do you want $result to contain the first and second entries of $data, but not the third (since it is the same as the first)?" - yes, basically im trying to remove duplicate items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel here: http://php.net/array-unique

Comment: Not sure if I got the answer first before this post was made but yea, I ended up using this function. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    public function test() {
        $data = array(
            array('foo' => 'alpha', 'bar' => 'bravo'),
            array('foo' => 'charlie', 'bar' => 'delta'),
            array('foo' => 'alpha', 'bar' => 'bravo'),
        );

        $result = array_filter($data, array('MyClass', 'isExist'));
        return $result;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$array_filterd = $obj->test();
```

Comment: im sorry, the question may have been misleading. I have edited it, kindly take a look.

Comment: using array_filter you can only access one element of your array that is used as input paramter for your isExist - you called it '@arr', but it is alwayys only one single array-element.